# Should I set the photo resolution as required before starting post-editing job?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop

My client is requiring the final work image to be in high resolution image, i.e. 9000px x 6000px - 300dpi.  I normally shoot the "still" product in RAW image.  Before starting my editing job (photoshop CC), should I convert the image size to the required size in order not to lose the details?

Thanks.

Comment: What camera are you using to take a 54 Mpix photo?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I guess Leica or Sony. Both worth a small car.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr The Sony a7R series sensor is "only" 42 Mpix, and the maximum resolution Leica sensor is 24 Mpix as far as I can see.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I only did  a quick google search without the technical details and it came up with a Leica S type 700 and an article about sony's new 54mpix camera from 2014. Didn't read further, because I am actually supposed to work

Comment: If it is a still shot (like a standing car) and you can do it in multiple exposures you don't need a high res camera you can use a more zoomed in lens and make a 3x2 or a 2x2 panorama then you have the resolution (or maybe even more) and you can work with it as one big raw file after stitching

Comment: can you pls edit your post to give us more details on what to shoot (still subject, moving subject, action shot,...) and if you have to do it in one exposure.

Comment: Your client doesn't understand that 300dpi is meaningless.

Comment: @Robin Not necessarily. The client could be inserting the images into a desktop publishing program that *does* pay attention to the 'dpi' field (which is actually ppi) in the EXIF data. They don't want to have to resize it themselves after inserting them. But that would mean the client is publishing something awful big!

Comment: @MichaelClark That's _super_ doubtful, as while desktop publishing programs may use that data as a default, they all allow arbitrary rescaling.

Comment: @mattdm As the comment above says, *"They don't want to have to resize it themselves after inserting it."*

Comment: Yeah, but that'd be super-weird, since it's so easy to do otherwise ­— and because in most cases the images they're working with won't have a dpi value and resolution that matches the frame size, so saving a click on one image would just be... well, weird.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr How did you know about [Leica's announcement of a 64 Mp sensor](https://www.dpreview.com/news/3590172611/leica-s3-with-64-megapixel-medium-format-sensor-announced) a week before it happened? ;-)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I could tell you, but you know, I'd have to kill you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch... Wait there.

You are a photographer. You are "limited" on what camera you have. Unless you are using a Phase One medium format camera or something similar you are most likely using a smaller image size.

You are a photographer, focus on preparing the best image you can. If your image is 24Mpx prepare the best 24Mpx image you can.

You are a photographer, the editing job as a photographer is adjusting the image; color, saturation, sharpness, contrast, dodge and burn... this kind of stuff. Do that on your original size.

---

Sayed that...

If your "editing job" is different from that you are not working as a photographer, but as a compositor, illustrator, graphic designer, so this is out of the scope of the forum, but let's address that as a graphic designer.

**Resampling an image is the last step; it is destructive; no detail will be "lost" or "gained" these resamplings are just to hide potential pixelation.**

You do not need 300ppi on a 30 inches print.

A 24Mpx image, or 6000px width, can give you a nice 200ppi print, which is enough for that size.

Do you want to be technical? Let's get rough here. 300 PPI on all prints is a myth, it is only necessary for halftoning images on flat sheet print, in fact, you could go with 212 PPI which is the square root of 2 multiplied by 150 (due the rotation of the screening on the black plate by 45°), which is the normal lineature (150 LPI) of a normal print on a coated paper using a 2400 DPI plate or negative printer... So, 200 PPI is more resolution than the one you see in any magazine. Phew.

But yeap. Increasing size as the last step on the OUTPUT file (Not on the working file) of 150% is not a big deal, so just do that as the last step and apply some sharpening afterward.

---

1. Work on your original file size.
2. Make an output file, probably a nice JPG or TIFF file and resample that.

Answer (score 5):

How certain are you that your client *requires* a 9000x6000 image (30"x20" at 300dpi)? You should strongly consider discussing your clients' *actual* needs with them. What they will be using the image for, etc?

If your camera does not natively produce such large files, increasing image sizes before editing will mainly just slow down your editing workflow. If your client insists on those particular image dimensions, resize with a "smart" algorithm ("preserve details" in Photoshop) as one of your final editing steps. Tell them up front that this is what you will be doing so that there will be no surprises later.